# Why YARN Application Master can require more that 1GB?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

On my hadoop cluster I have an issue when ApplicationMaster(AM) killed by NodeManager because AM tries to allocate more than default 1GB. MR application, that AM is in charge of, is a mapper only job(1(!) mapper, no reducers, downloads data from remote source). At the moment when AM killed, MR job is ok (uses about 70% of ram limit). MR job doesn't have any custom counters, distributes caches etc, just downloads data (by portions) via custom input format.
To fix this issue, I raised memory limit for AM, but I want to know what is the reason of eating 1GB (!) for a trivial job like mine?

Comment: Whats the size of your input, and how much did you raise the memory imit for AM

Comment: At the time of AM failure Map job produced about 50GB of gzipped SequenceFile. Map task reads input via jdbc, fetching 100000 rows each time.

Comment: So you are using DBInputFormat as input type right

Comment: No, I'm using my custom input format (it's working with stored procedures, while DBInputFormat only with tables)